# Creating files in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I want to create a file using C++, but I have no idea how to do it. For example I want to create a text file named `Hello.txt`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

One way to do this is to create an instance of the ofstream class, and use it to write to your file. Here's a link to a website that has some example code, and some more information about the standard tools available with most implementations of C++:

[ofstream reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream)

For completeness, here's some example code:

```
// using ofstream constructors.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  

std::ofstream outfile ("test.txt");

outfile << "my text here!" << std::endl;

outfile.close();
```

You want to use std::endl to end your lines. An alternative is using '\n' character. These two things are different, std::endl flushes the buffer and writes your output immediately while '\n' allows the outfile to put all of your output into a buffer and maybe write it later.

Comment: Not to mention that std::endl also writes the correct platform specific newline character string.

Comment: To Limberg: thats wrong. "endl: Effects: Calls os.put(os.widen('\n')), then os.flush()" -- C++ standard, 27.6.2.7/1

Comment: @Grant Limberg:  '\n' also writes the correct platform specific newline--it's translated as appropriate by the ostream internals.

Comment: @James Thompson:  The only reason to use std::endl is if you really need to guarantee that the buffer is flushed to the file IMMEDIATELY.  Otherwise, it's a needless pessimization (file i/o is very expensive!).

Comment: @Grant Limberg: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Newline_in_programming_languages

Comment: When using ofstream for writing to a file, then no file locking is implemented. It is possible for others to read the half-written file, or for others to open another ofstream and write simultaneously.

Comment: important note: file will not be created if folder does not exist, e.g. std::ofstream("testDir/test.txt") will only work if "testDir" folder exists;

Answer (score 44):

Do this with a file stream. When a `std::ofstream` is closed, the file is created. I prefer the following code, because the OP only asks to create a file, not to write in it:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream { "Hello.txt" };
    // Hello.txt has been created here
}
```

The stream is destroyed right after its creation, so the stream is closed inside the destructor and thus the file is created.

Comment: how change from ( ) to { }  make it create the file and close ?

Comment: @Jackt It's not `()` vs `{}`, it's just due to the destructor running. But you're right, there is an error. I've reverted to a previous revision, there has been a faulty edition.

Comment: even better, tnx!

Answer (score 13):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::ofstream o("Hello.txt");

  o << "Hello, World\n" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The \n in the string is redundant when using std::endl.

Comment: The return 0; in the function is redundant when using "int main()"

Comment: True, but I like to explicitly flush the output buffer.

Comment: The #include <iostream> is redundant when using std::ofstream.

Comment: endl does more than flush: it outputs a newline too. So either print \n then std::flush, or just use std::endl.

Comment: streams get flushed on destruction, so the std::endl is completely superfluous in this case.  However, the "return 0" is definitely NOT redundant.  It was a common case in C to imply "return 0", but that is not true with C++.

Comment: @Tom: basic.start.main: "If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing: return 0;".

Comment: also std::endl is not superfluous. it outputs a '\n' before flushing. omitting it will result in only one trailing newline instead of two. oO

Comment: litb no one event wanted 2 newlines, sean thought he was only outputting one

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, both positive and negative.  You are all absolutely correct, I included an unnecessary std::endl and #include.  My personal preference regarding the return statement is to always include them, even in methods returning void.

Comment: +1 for noting that ofstream is automatically closed when it goes out of scope!

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


std::string filename = "/tmp/filename.txt";

int main() {
  std::ofstream o(filename);

  o << "Hello, World\n";

  return 0;
}
```

This is what I had to do in order to use a variable for the filename instead of a regular string.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ("Hello.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

File (Hello.txt) is created even without ofstream name, and this is the difference from Mr. Boiethios answer.

Comment: Ladies, Gentlemen, please let me say you that when someone asks what to do for get some result, and reads an answer, thinks that EVERYTHING in answer IS NEEDED for get this result. For this, answer should include only WHAT IS NEEDED for get the desired result. Regards.

Comment: caveat: if the raw "Hello.txt" was replaced by an already existing variable, this wouldn't compile for MSVC17.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a file with some content and don't need to deal with the `ofstream` after that you can simply write:

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream("file.txt") << "file content";
}
```

no need to manually close the file, deal with variables, etc. The file is created, written, and closed in the same line.

Answer (score -1):

```
/*I am working with turbo c++ compiler so namespace std is not used by me.Also i am familiar with turbo.*/

#include<iostream.h>
#include<iomanip.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h> //required while dealing with files
void main ()
{
clrscr();
ofstream fout; //object created **fout**
fout.open("your desired file name + extension");
fout<<"contents to be written inside the file"<<endl;
fout.close();
getch();
}
```

After running the program the file will be created inside the bin folder in your compiler folder itself.