# How to create an empty file in linux using c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to create an empty file in ubuntu with c++ and i tried many ways and it keeps failing and show this error

> error: no matching function to 'std::basic_ofstream::open(std::cxxll::...

my code:

```
ifstream f(saltFile.c_str());

if (f.good())
{
     cout << saltFile + " file already existed" << endl;
}
else
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open (saltFile, ios::out);
    cout << saltFile << " created!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating files in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478075/creating-files-in-c)

Comment: `file.open (saltFile.c_str(), ...`. The C++98 version has only a prototype with `const char *`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Did you enable C++11 or higher?

Comment: Creating an empty file is not 1:1 with creating files in general, so I agree that this is not a duplicate question. There are challenges to account for with empty file creation such as avoiding accidental encoding, empty lines, etc.

Answer (score 15):

If you want a completely empty file, you can use `<fstream>`'s `std::ofstream`, and not even call the object.

Note: this assumes that the file does not already exist. If it does then you should remove it first if you want it replaced with a blank file.

### Empty file creation

```
std::ofstream output(file_path);
```

### Creating a file with content

```
std::ofstream output(file_path);
output << L"Hello, world!";
```

#### *Funny side-note*:

Before trying out just using `ofstream`'s constructor I tried `output << nullptr;` to see what would happen...

[image]

*Precious*

Comment: Note from noob to self: calling `std::ofstream(file_path);` works too if you don't need to keep a handle pointing to the opened file and just want to "touch" the file.

Comment: If you just open file such way ```std::ofstream output(file_path)```, it would not be created! you need to make ```output.flush()``` somewhere or just make ```std::ofstream(file_path).flush();```.

Comment: Maybe it's specific to your flavor of C++? What are you using?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a C++11 or later compiler, you can certainly use:

```
else
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open (saltFile, ios::out);
    cout << saltFile << " created!" << endl;
}
```

If you have a pre-C++11 compiler, the call to `open()` needs to be tweaked a little bit.

```
file.open (saltFile.c_str(), ios::out);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also close the file right after the `.open()`?

Comment: @einpoklum, one could but it is not necessary. `ofstream file;` is in the scope of the `else` block.

Comment: Yes, but your answer doesn't clarify that these lines are within short blocks. I'd emphasize the closing aspect.

Comment: @einpoklum, you convinced me.

Answer (score 1):

to create a file you can use ofstream

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {  
std::ofstream outfile;

outfile.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::app); // append instead of overwrite
 outfile << "Data"; 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not forget to do proper error handling as well:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>  
#include <filesystem>
#include <spdlog/fmt/fmt.h>
#include <cerrno>

int main() {
    auto const fileName = "/test.txt";
    std::ofstream outfile (fileName);
    if (not outfile.good()) {
        auto const errNo = errno;
        auto const errMsg = fmt::format("Failed to create file {}: {} : {}", fileName, errNo, std::strerror(errNo)); 
        throw std::runtime_error(errMsg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```