# Why is this not producing a file in the current directory?

Tags: c++, io

I have some trouble with producing files in C++. I consulted this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478075/creating-files-in-c/42767681) but when I try using it, it doesn't produce a file. What I wrote:

```
//~/Documents/Test_CPP/ex2/main_2.cpp

#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream file("Hello.txt");
    // Hello.txt has been created here
}
```

I compile it with the command `g++ main_2.cpp` and run it with `./a.out`. I don't really know what could go wrong here, except theorizing that the file might be produced not in the current directory but somewhere else. So I tried changing `Hello.txt` to `~/Documents/Test_CPP/ex2/Hello.txt`, which doesn't change anything. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "the file is not produced in the current directory but somewhere else" - where?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I thought it might be produced somewhere else, but I didn't know. So I tried giving it the full Path.. I'm sorry, but I don't think I understand your question correctly..

Comment: My question is very simple. You say the file is not created in the current working directory. So all I am asking is, where *is* the file created?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Ah, I'm sorry. It's not created at all.. At least I can't find it..

Comment: After you have answered Jesper's question, take a look at your second statement `~/Documnets/.../main_2.cpp` what are you doing there compared to `Hello.txt`?

Comment: Be careful with setting an existing file as an output file, because that file may then be overwritten!

Comment: @rezi thank you for pointing that out.. I misspelled when writing the question, I did write `file(~/... /Hello. txt) `

Comment: @JesperJuhl I just tried searching for the file with `find / -name Hello.txt` and it really isn't anywhere on the machine.

Comment: The code works for me. If the file doesn't exist, it's created, and if it does exist, it's emptied. Are you in a directory where you have permission to create files? (Try something like `echo "File Contents" > Hello.txt` from the Linux command line? Add error checking within your code to see if `file` is open?)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem on macOS with Xcode if you use some IDEs you should point to build-dir.

Comment: and according to your second statement "I tried changing Hello.txt to ~/Documents/Test_CPP/ex2/main_2.cpp" you should fail here because file exist and already in use try "~/Documents/Test_CPP/ex2/test.txt"

Comment: I'm running everything from a Linux shell.

Comment: please point compiler version and Linux distributive type and kernel version

Comment: gcc 9.2.0, Manjaro, 4.19.56-1-surface

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: use std::filesystem::current_path(). It will give full path to you elf\exe dir.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>


int main() {

    std::string file_name{"Hello.txt"};

    auto path{std::filesystem::current_path()};
    path = path / file_name;
    if (std::filesystem::exists(path)) {
        std::filesystem::remove(path);
    } 

    std::ofstream out_stream(path, std::ios::out);
    if (!out_stream.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error open file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    out_stream << "test" << std::endl;

    out_stream.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This can sometimes happen if you do not properly terminate the connection to the file

EG.
`file.close();`

This must be done before the program terminates.

Comment: The `std::ofstream` destructor calls `close()` automatically.